# How can Google+ for Android be so fluid?

Tags: android, image, scroll

Google+ is a rather fluid app in my old Dell Venue (Android 2.3.3), even with animations. One thing that intrigues me is that while you scroll the lists it paints images in the view (user pictures, post pictures, etc.) and it doesn't lag the scroll.

Currently, we already use the most common best practices in the ListView:
 - Using the view holder pattern
 - Recycling views
 - Loading images async
 - Loading images only when the user is not scrolling (by using onScrollStateChanged)

We're using AndroidUniversalImageLoader library. The problem is whenever the image gets drawn in the UI, the list scrolls lags.

What do you guys suggest to make it smoother?

Answer (score 2):

with `AsyncTasks` and `caching` of images, you can see when the app first loads that it gets a certain number of posts, then when you scroll to the end of the list it fetches more.

Comment: already using async tasks and caching. The problem is when the image gets drawn in the UI. Google+, for instance, doesn't lag when the images are drawn. Why?

Answer (score 0):

you can check more on below link

http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

Comment: we already do all those techniques in our adapter. Check the question edit.